Is smoothness preserved under an isometric isomorphism?
Let $(X, \|.\|_1)$ is isometrically isomorphic to $(X, \|.\|_2)$ and $\|.\|_2\leq \|.\|_1$. Assume that $x_0$ is a smooth point of $(X, \|.\|_1)$ and $\|x_0\|_2=1$. According to the definition of a smooth point let the collection of support functionals at $x_0$ be
$$J(x_0)=\{\mu x_1^*:|\mu|=1\},\qquad x_1^*\in (X^*, \|.\|_1^*)\quad \text{and}\quad \|x_1^*\|=1.$$
My question: Is $x_0$ also smooth in $(X, \|.\|_2)?$ Is the comparison between two norms necessary to conclude this?
I haven't been able to proceed. Please help. Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Cross posted on Math.SE. While this is not forbidden, the accepted good practice is to wait at least a week in order to let the members of the other site to post a reasonably good answer, and to put a cross posting notice on the body of the question. Otherwise, it seems you want to issue a competition between the StackExchanges to get as soon as possible the sought for answer, which is not the purpose of this Q&A sites.

Many thanks for the suggestion. I will remember this and definitely do accordingly. Pardon me as of now. I badly need a lead for the question.

I think you need to specify the map $X\to X$ that implements the isometric isomorphism. This map will send a smooth point for $\lVert\cdot\rVert_1$ to a smooth point for $\lVert\cdot\rVert$. However, I don't see why a point $x_0$ would be a smooth point for both norms simultaneously.

$\newcommand\R{\Bbb R}$Counterexample: $X=\R^2$, $\|x\|_1=|u|+|v|$ and $\|x\|_2=\max(|u|,|v|)$ for $x=(u,v)\in\R^2$.
Then $\|\cdot\|_2\le\|\cdot\|_1$ and the map $\R^2\ni(u,v)\mapsto\frac12\,(u-v,u+v)$ is an isometric isomorphism of $(X,\|\cdot\|_2)$ to $(X,\|\cdot\|_1)$. However, $x_0:=(1,1)$ (with $\|x_0\|_2=1$) is smooth in $(X,\|\cdot\|_1)$ but not in $(X,\|\cdot\|_2)$.

But $|(1, 1)|_1\neq 1$.

What is your definition of a smooth point?

A norm one point $x_0$ is called a smooth point if the collection of its support functionals contains all the unimodular scalar multiplication of only one support functional, i.e., $J(x_0)={\mu x_1^:|\mu|=1},\qquad x_1^\in (X^, |.|_1^)\quad \text{and}\quad |x_1^*|=1.$

@Tuh : I cannot parse this definition.

Ok. Let me brief it another way: a norm one element $x_0$ is called smooth if the set $J(x_0)={x^\in X^: |x^|=1, x^(x_0)=1}$ is singleton.

@Tuh : OK. Now I understand the definition.

The map also not an isometry since $|(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2})|_1=1$ and the image of $(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2})$ is $(0, \frac{1}{2})$ but $|(0, \frac{1}{2})|_2\neq 1$.

@Tuh : The isomorphism is from $(X,|\cdot|_2)$ to $(X,|\cdot|_1)$, not vice versa.

can you please explain it. I am very sorry. I didn't understand your statement. Both the normed spaces are isometrically isomorphic. Then isn't the isomorphism from both side?

@Tuh : An isomorphism does not have to coincide with its inverse. In this case, the inverse of the isomorphism $(u,v)\mapsto\frac12,(u-v,u+v)$ is $(s,t)\mapsto(s+t,t-s)$.

Ok got it. Thank you for your cooperation. Many thanks
